# How to refresh Access Token on Spotify SDK for Android?

Tags: android, token, asp.net-web-api, spotify

I'm making an Android's app using [Spotify SDK](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk) and [Spotify Web Api Android](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android) from kaaes. What's the best way to refresh my access token? Since i need to keep the user logged.

I don't want that my app ask for log in everytime the users open the app.

How can I handle this ?

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: 401 Unauthorized
Login to Spotify failed because of invalid credentials
```

Thanks for your time and help!
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the Authorization Code flow from the Spotify Web API to obtain a refresh token that you can use to obtain a new access token when yours expires.

For that you need to have a web service with which you communicate from the Android app.

There is more information on this on https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/47

Comment: Yeah .. i read a lot of stuff that Kaees said. But couldn't find any particular code to do it. I already find the way to do it! Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is having trouble with this issue, I made a gist you can use to stand up a free cloud function and handle this process:

https://gist.github.com/rldaulton/8b87216715d3cea828b5a9b27e300a3f