# Refresh token in spotify android sdk?

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, spotify, refresh-token

I'm making an Android's app using Spotify SDK. Spotify access token expires after some time.

To retrieve refresh token i found web based api authentication solution.

Can we get refresh token using spotify android sdk?, Is this feature added in the sdk now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh Access Token on Spotify SDK for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085038/how-to-refresh-access-token-on-spotify-sdk-for-android)

Comment: @RED_ I am looking for solution to get refresh token using spotify android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

In [Spotify Android SDK github.com](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk) project they say they won't implement refresh token functionality on the SDK, so you have to implement it yourself in some backend using [this Web API Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) as reference.